# Define a function with parameters in MASM assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm trying to write a function in x86 assembly language that will accept three parameters. Is it possible to define a function in MASM assembly language with multiple parameters?

```
//this is pseudocode: I'm trying to convert this to a valid macro in MASM
//if var1 is equal to var2, jump to the label jumpToHere
function jumpIfEqual(var1, var2, jumpToHere){
    cmp var1, var2;
    je jumpToHere;
}
```

If I could write a valid function to do this, then `jumpIfEqual(5, 5, jumpToHere)` would be equivalent to

```
cmp 5, 5;
je jumpToHere;
```

Comment: Parameters, huh? Are you interfacing it with a high level language? Are you sure doing the same in the HLL won't suffice?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, No, I'm just trying to make my code slightly less verbose (and easier to understand). `jumpIfEqual(var1, var2, jumpToHere)` is a bit easier to read than `cmp 5, 5;
je jumpToHere;`.

Comment: Do a macro. You don't need a function. M in MASM stands for macros :)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I found an introduction to macros in MASM here: http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH08/CH08-7.html

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Is it possible for a macro in MASM to have more than 2 parameters?

Comment: Sure it can. Couldn't you just try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, you can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01d2az3t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

For example:

```
jumpIfEqual PROC var1:DWORD, var2:DWORD, jmpAddress:DWORD
    mov eax,var1
    cmp eax,var2
    jne skip
    pop eax
    push jmpAddress
    skip:
    ret
jumpIfEqual ENDP

....

push OFFSET jumpToHere
mov eax, 5
push eax
push eax
call jumpIfEqual
```

Comment: It represents any additional code that your program might contain in between the procedure and the place(s) from where you call it.

Comment: I did [a Google search for "masm assembly language function"](https://www.google.com/#q=assembly+language+function+masm&hl=en&psj=1&ei=8ctQUZeHBsTx0gGMxICQBg&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmQ&fp=dc8abc04c054405e&biw=1366&bih=639), and found that most of the search results weren't about defining functions. I've done many other searches as well, and still haven't found any relevant information. Is there any other documentation that actually discusses how to define functions in masm?

Comment: I finally found a relevant search query: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=assembly+language+(define%7Ccreate%7Cmake)+(method%7Cfunction%7Cprocedure)+(masm%7Cx86)&oq=assembly+language+(define%7Ccreate%7Cmake)+(method%7Cfunction%7Cprocedure)+(masm%7Cx86)&gs_l=serp.12...14954.19347.4.20508.12.12.0.0.0.2.210.995.11j0j1.12.0...0.0...1c.1.7.serp.LkLbcPDwmBs&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=dc8abc04c054405e&biw=1366&bih=639

Comment: I tried running this program on ideone.com (with `....` removed), and got a few compiler errors. The compiler errors are shown here: http://ideone.com/xNtLhT

Comment: I've never heard of ideone.com. But my example code uses MASM syntax (since that's what the question was about), so unless the ideone assembler supports MASM syntax it's not going to be able to compile this code.

Comment: It appears that `jumpToHere` isn't defined in the code above. Is this a typo?

Comment: No, I left it out since I figured you already had a label like that in your code. This was just showing the principle - it's not a complete program.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.  Can you tell me if this is a standard way to pass parameters to procedures in MASM or, if it is, are there also alternative ways? My book is not very clear on passing parameters and so far this method is the only one that works.

Comment: You miss one "," after "PROC" in the first line. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/proc?view=msvc-160 for details.

Comment: Neither MASM 6.14 nor 12.00 requires a comma before the first parameter. I'm not sure why the documentation is written that way. Perhaps it's a typo, or maybe it's referring to some other version of MASM.