# Passing variables into a PROC in MASM

Tags: assembly, parameters, x86, masm

I am trying to pass 3 variables into my own PROC called `DifferentInputs`

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

.data               ;date values
    val1 DWORD 102
    val2 DWORD 104
    val3 DWORD 102

.code               ;Code
main PROC
    call DifferentInputs

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

;Takes 3 inputs and checks to see if any of them are the same
DifferentInputs PROC, val1:DWORD, val2:DWORD, val3:DWORD
    mov eax, val1
    cmp eax, val2

    ret
DifferentInputs ENDP
End main
```

I have followed my professors code but I'm getting the error `symbol redefinition : val1`
I also fallowed this example from another question. [Define a function with parameters in MASM assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345645/define-a-function-with-parameters-in-masm-assembly-language)

But I am missing something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the code you are showing here what produces that error? I see you have commented out 3 lines, and if those were put back in I could see you getting the error. When you define a function using PROC the calling convention for the current language type will be used. Is it "C"? The code you are showing is not complete so its hard to tell. The parameters will be passed on the stack. You can try calling with invoke `DifferentInputs,1,2,3` for example or `push 3` `push 2` `push 1` `call DifferentInputs` . Using Invoke allows the assembler to use the right calling convention and is preferred

Comment: If you do want to use `Invoke` to call your `PROC` rather than manually setting up parameters on the stack and using `call` you will also have to add a prototype at the top like `DifferentInputs PROTO val1:DWORD, val2:DWORD, val3:DWORD`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Can you show me what that would look like? Our teacher has done this in many slides but nothing is on one page. The book has things omitted as well and I can't make sense of what needs to be put it or taken out.

Comment: Something like: https://pastebin.com/P1CXRPv3  (Your code here isn't complete since you must be including include files/headers to define Windows prototypes and constants etc)

Comment: Thank you. Why don't you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: That's okay, you can self answer your question. You're welcome.